# Our blog is launched as of this week! (Feedback here please!)

Tags: discussion, blogoverflow

You may remember our topic at

> [Blogoverflow blog anyone? If you want to help with the DBA.SE blog, here's the signup list?](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248/blogoverflow-blog-anyone-if-you-want-to-help-with-the-dba-se-blog-heres-the-s)

where we asked for volunteers to help write our blogoverflow blog, and to commit to writing it.

Well, this is just a bit of an announcement that the blog is "up" and we have our first few authors working on drafts right now for posting. If you'll kindly bear with us as we work on the mechanics of the process, and if you have feedback, this is the place to give it, rather than on the individual blog entries.

And if you just need to recommend a topic, that should go here:

> [Blogoverflow Topic Requests! (Summer 2012)](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/700/blogoverflow-topic-requests)

Hmmm, I think that's it to say for right now, except to remind everyone our blog entry is at http://dba.blogoverflow.com.